# SoapMessageValidation Policy Apigee

Tags: apigee

I am trying to validate my yahoo weather response with xsd using Soap Message Validation policy. I am referring to xml which I get in response from http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12797282

And I am receiving following error response:
{"fault":"{\"detail\":{\"errorcode\":\"steps.messagevalidation.Failed\"},\"faultstring\":\"MessageValidation soapmessagevalidation-1 failed with reason: \\"root element must be {http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/soap\/envelope\/}Envelope or {http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2003\/05\/soap-envelope}Envelope [Line:2]\\"\"}"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your response is RSS 1.0 and is not SOAP. The error is about not finding expected SOAP elements.